# How to remove last element from array

Tags: powershell

I want to run a powershell command, get info about a current windows service.

For example for Redis:

Current path is : "C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-server.exe"

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service |?{$_.Name -like 'redis*'} | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, state, startmode, @{Name="Path"; Expression={$_.PathName.split('"')}}| convertto-json
```

```json
{
    "Name":  "Redis",
    "DisplayName":  "Redis",
    "state":  "Running",
    "startmode":  "Auto",
    "Path":  "C:\\Program Files\\Redis\\redis-server.exe"
}
```

But I want to use this path : "C:\Program Files\Redis"

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service |?{$_.Name -like 'redis*'} | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, state, startmode, @{Name="Path"; Expression={$_.PathName.split('"')[1].split('\\')[0..3]}}| convertto-json
```

```json
{
    "Name":  "Redis",
    "DisplayName":  "Redis",
    "state":  "Running",
    "startmode":  "Auto",
    "Path":  {
                 "value":  [
                               "C:",
                               "Program Files",
                               "Redis",
                               "redis-server.exe"
                           ],
                 "Count":  4
             }
}
```

Is there anyway to command like this

```
...split('\\')[0..length-1]}}
```

Comment: `$a[0..($a.length-2)]` or `$a[-$a.length..-2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object -SkipLast 1`:

```
@{Name='Path';Expression={$_.PathName.split('"')[1].split('\\') |Select -SkipLast 1}}
```

Although a simpler option is to use `Split-Path` to remove the leaf part of the path before splitting:

```
@{Name='Path';Expression={($_.PathName.split('"')[1] |Split-Path -Parent).Split('\')}}
```

Comment: Thanks, awesome. It works. So I was wondering if there any simpler way to get parent path? For example skipping last value of array and print like 'C:\ProgramFiles\Redis' ?

Comment: @user20732118 `"C:\ProgramFiles\Redis\redis-server.exe" |Split-Path -Parent` :)

Comment: Huh. You're awesome again.  Than  `Get-WmiObject win32_service |?{$_.Name -like 'redis*'} | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, state, @{Name='Path';Expression={$_.PathName.split('"')[1] | Split-Path -Parent}} | convertto-json` is best for me :) Thanks a lot.